# Git ghost commit

Tags: git, version-control, commit

I noticed couple commits that I cannot make sense of. The commits have these properties:

1. It is present in the master branch (e.g. `git log master | grep <sha1>` returns an occurrence)
2. It has proper content (`git show <sha1>` indicates that the blob is not empty)
3. It changes file/with/path/xyz
4. Running `git log master -- file/with/path/xyz | grep <sha1>` doesn't return any occurrences)
5. file/with/path/xyz at master HEAD doesn't contain changes from commit

Basically the commit is present in the branch, but is not reflected in the file content.

I'm not the commit author. There was a chain of merges that brought the commit into master, and I'm also not the person who did the merges, e.g. I pulled this `master` from our `origin`.

What could bring our tree to such state, and how can I fix this? Is there a way to find all such commits? There is more than one, but I have no idea how many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items 4 and 5 are tied together.  As the [git log documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) says:

> `[--] <path>...`
>
> Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that
>   match the specified paths came to be. See *History Simplification*
>   below for details and other simplification modes.

If you give `git log` the `--full-history` option you should see the commit re-appear.

> What could bring our tree to such state ...

Typically an incorrect merge.

Merge can be told to ignore some changes in case of conflicts (e.g., `-X ours`, not to be confused with `-s ours`).

In any merge, before you actually commit the result of the merge, you can *change the tree*.  (This is of course much easier after a failed merge, when you *have to*, or if you use the `--no-commit` option.)

In any case, the tree resulting from a merge is whatever tree you set, or—if you don't change anything—git's best guess as to what the right result is based on options passed to the merge command.

> and how can I fix this?

It may not be broken (though the fact that you're asking suggests that it is).  In general, when merging two revisions, git's automated merge *usually* does the right thing, but to prevent future occurrences of whatever is wrong with the result, whoever is doing the merge must check.

> Is there a way to find all such commits?

Read through the `History Simplification` section in the `git log` command.  It sounds like you're interested in seeing which commits are or are not "TREESAME" (as it is called here) with respect to particular files.